# retrieving the value in a json array encounters errors

Tags: java, json

Output of String return: `[{"type":1, "txt":"ERROR"}]`. I'm trying to get the content of `txt` key which is `ERROR`. And that 
by transforming string return into an array. However I'm getting some errors commented next to each line on the follow code.

Any insight? I tried everything to retrieve the value of `txt`.

```
Vector<ClsReturn> ret = null;
ret = ds.id(collection, "fs",in_uri );
String return = JSONArray.toJSONString(ret);
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(ret);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(return); //The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined

for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){ //The method length() is undefined for the type JSONArray
   JSONObject jsonObj  = array.getJSONObject(i); //The method getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray
   System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("txt"));
}
```

Comment: You should use `JSONObject json = new JSONObject('[{"type":1, "txt":"ERROR"}]');` and then you can do `JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("")` for the array which I think would be empty. And then do `array.getJSONObject("txt");`

Comment: `return` is a keyword in java so cannot be used as a String variable name

Comment: I suppose that `return` name for the `String` object is a typo in OP code sample since it is a reserved word and then the program not even compiles so It can't throw the exceptions about `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        String retur = JSONArray.toJSONString(ret);
        JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(retur); 

        int i = 0;

        while(i < array .length()){
            myJsonObject = array .getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(myJsonObject.getString("txt"));
            i++;
        }
```